# ciclo for anidado con matriz c++

Tags: c++, bucle-for, matriz

no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre programacion y para la universidad me pidieron un ciclo for anidado con forma de matriz y el problema empieza en la fila 12 y 13 que me tira un error que la a y b ya se esta declarando y al borrar ya no se declara tampoco, ya intente de todo, busque de todo y no me funciona nada. ayuda bandita:(

```
int a=0, b=0;

int m1[a][b];
int m2[a][b];

cout << "Ingrese Primer Numero: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Ingrese Segundo Numero: ";
cin >> b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Las matrices en memoria automática<sup>1</sup> necesitan un tamaño conocido en [tiempo de compilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_compilaci%C3%B3n), sin embargo las estás definiendo con un tamaño que es una variable cuyo valor sólo se conoce en [tiempo de ejecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n).

Pero aunque esto funcionase con las variables `a` y `b`, las matrices `m1` y `m2` no cambian de tamaño automágicamente al leer las variables. El código de C++ se lee de arriba a abajo y lo que se escribe abajo no afecta a lo que se había escrito arriba:

```
int m1[a][b]; // Esto no es C++ valido, 'a' y 'b' deben ser constantes, no variables.
int m2[a][b]; // Esto no es C++ valido, 'a' y 'b' deben ser constantes, no variables.

cout << "Ingrese Primer Numero: ";
cin >> a; // Esta lectura no afecta al tamaño de 'm1' ni 'm2' que ya fueron definidas.
cout << "Ingrese Segundo Numero: ";
cin >> b; // Esta lectura no afecta al tamaño de 'm1' ni 'm2' que ya fueron definidas.
```

Mi consejo es que si quieres un tamaño dinámico de matrices, las crees usando vectores:

```
using fila_t = std::vector<int>;
using matriz_t std::vector<fila_t>;

int a=0, b=0;
cout << "Ingrese Primer Numero: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Ingrese Segundo Numero: ";
cin >> b;

matriz_t  m1(a, fila_t(b)); // Matriz de 'a' filas de 'b' elementos
matriz_t  m2(a, fila_t(b)); // Matriz de 'a' filas de 'b' elementos
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>La memoria automática es la que no se pide con `new`.